# Windows 7 Hover Preview buttons C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-7, taskbar

I was using iTunes recently, and I saw that when you hovered over the iTunes logo in the taskbar, some buttons were underneath the preview, which enable you to control music etc.

This is what it looks like:
[image: Preview]

How can I get something like those buttons in C# and / or .NET in winforms or likewise?

Update: Is it possible to get this feature in XP or vista as well in C#?

Comment: Darin's got the answer to your question. As for your update, no. Only the Windows 7 taskbar supports this. There is no support in XP or Vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [TaskBar API](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/02/12/windows-7-taskbar-apis.aspx) for Windows 7. There are also [managed wrappers](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).